# Trouble at inserting values into the table

Tags: jsp, jdbc, javabeans

```
<%
String cusId = request.getParameter("UserName");
String cusPwd = request.getParameter("Pwd");
String dChoc = request.getParameter("dChoc");
String wChoc = request.getParameter("wChoc");
String sToys = request.getParameter("sToys");
String bdayCard = request.getParameter("bdayCard");
String weddCard = request.getParameter("weddCard");
String bigOrna = request.getParameter("bigOrna");
String smallOrna = request.getParameter("smallOrna");
String candle = request.getParameter("candle");
String keyCha = request.getParameter("keyCha");
String tow = request.getParameter("tow");

Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:customer_data");

Statement s = con.createStatement();
try{
int status = 0;
//error here
    status = s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table1 (Soft_Toys,Dark_Chocolate,White_Chocolate,Birthday_Card,Wedding_card,Big_Ornaments,Small_Ornaments,Candles,KeyChain,Customer_Id,Customer_pw,Towels)"+ "values('"+sToys+"','"+dChoc+"','"+wChoc+"','"+bdayCard+"','"+weddCard+"','"+bigOrna+"','"+smallOrna+"','"+candle+"','"+keyCha+"','"+cusId+"','"+cusPwd+"','"+tow+"')");
}
catch
if(status>0)
System.out.println("Update successful");
else
System.out.println("Error!!!");


s.close();
con.close();
```

%>

Comment: Not related to your problem, but: you shouldn't be using the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It's deprecated, buggy and slow (and it will be removed in Java8). Use a proper JDBC driver instead. Secondly please use a `PreparedStatement` to protect yourself from SQL injection (and make life working with non-string values much easier)

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: in status = s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table blah blah blah i cant insert any values into the database. i know the sql statement is wrong. @R.S

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its my school that is using it. i have no control over it. just trying to learn and get things done.

Comment: You need to see what error the insert statement is generating. Either catch the exception and output the message to the console, or run the insert statement in a SQL client and see what you get back.

Comment: Put some curly braces around your catch and the if-else. Get in the practice of making code readable. You can get the error also catch(Exception ex){ out.print(ex.getMessage(); } then you'll know what the actual error is.